# How to include a variable data into a SQL Statement

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know, how to include a variable as a part of a SQL statement, to clarify more about my question, here is the code

```
declare @PartNo as nvarchar(20)
declare @PPFno as nvarchar(20)
declare @Dimension as nvarchar(30)
declare @cursor CURSOR
declare @colname as nvarchar(30)
declare @top as integer
declare @query as nvarchar(MAX)
declare @categoryid NVARCHAR(MAX) 

set @cursor = CURSOR FOR 
    (select [Name] from sys.columns where object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'ProductProperty') and [Name] like 'T%' and [name] <> 'TEMP')order by [Name] asc

    OPEN @cursor

    FETCH NEXT

    FROM @cursor INTO @colname
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        --set @query =  (select @colname from ProductProperty where PartNo = @PartNo  and PPFNo = @PPFno )

        --set @query = 'select distinct '+@colname+' from ProductProperty where PartNo = '''+@PartNo+'''  and PPFNo = '''+@PPFno+''' and DName = '''+@Dimension+''''

BEGIN

EXEC sp_executesql N'set @categoryid = (select distinct @colname from ProductProperty where PartNo = @PartNo  and PPFNo = @PPFno and DName = @Dimension)', 
N'@colname nvarchar(30), @PartNo nvarchar(20), @PPFno nvarchar(20),@Dimension nvarchar(30), @categoryid NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @colname,@PartNo, @PPFno,@Dimension, @categoryid OUTPUT

select @categoryid,@colname ,@PartNo

END
    --end

    FETCH NEXT

    FROM @cursor INTO @colName
    END

    CLOSE @cursor
    DEALLOCATE @cursor
```

Please do take note I did not included the variable types. I would just want to know how can `@colname` become part of the SQL Statement.

To Elaborate more. Using this code, I am receiving this data

[image]

Where `T1` is the table name. I want to create a query where I could pass table names into a variable, then retrieve the contents of that query.

So the SQL Query should look like this:

`select T1 from ProductProperty`

But I am not receiving the query, instead, I am receiving the variable data, which is in the screenshot above.

The problem is, if you might notice in my code, I have the variable `@categoryid` as  a output parameter. This is to check the contents of the query.

it seems like I am producing a query which looks like this

`select 'T1' from ProductProperty`

May I ask, what am I doing wrong? If you would want additional information, please do tell me.

EDIT:

completed the query for more clarification

Comment: Without dynamic SQL is it working?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Yep, its working. If I pass a static query, for example `select T1 from table`, with the parameters and all, I can retreive the data that I wanted.

Comment: I m not more familiar with Output param so if you can post expected data and available data then will help

Comment: `select distinct ' + @colname + ' from...` (watch out for SQL injection vulnerability though, depending on the source of `@colname`)

Comment: @Diado That would work if I will only pass 1 data, I also need to get the value of the query, check if its null or not, the process it again.

Comment: If you need to call it multiple times for different tables names, just update the value of `@colname` prior to calling `sp_executesql` in a loop (or however you're performing the multiple calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are telling it to select the value of the `@colname` variable itself as the first value in your query, *not* the value of the column name stored in the variable. This is the equivalent of doing:

```
SELECT @colname;
```

What you need to do is output the value of the `@colname` variable into the SQL string you are passing to `sp_executesql`. As long as the `@colname` variable isn't entered by the user, you can concatenate it into the string passed to `sp_executesql`, as follows:

```
DECLARE @SqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SqlQuery = N'set @categoryid = (select distinct ' + @colname + ' from ProductProperty 
where PartNo = @PartNo  and PPFNo = @PPFno and DName = @Dimension)';

EXEC sp_executesql @SqlQuery, 
@PartNo nvarchar(20), @PPFno nvarchar(20),@Dimension 
nvarchar(30), @categoryid NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @PartNo, @PPFno,@Dimension, 
@categoryid OUTPUT

select @categoryid, @colname, @PartNo
```

That will effectively give you:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'set @categoryid = (select distinct T1 from ProductProperty 
where PartNo = @PartNo  and PPFNo = @PPFno and DName = @Dimension)', 
@PartNo nvarchar(20), @PPFno nvarchar(20),@Dimension 
nvarchar(30), @categoryid NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @PartNo, @PPFno,@Dimension, 
@categoryid OUTPUT
```

Comment: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure saveProdPropSampDta, Line 38
Incorrect syntax near '+'.` it points out in `distinct ' + @colname + ' ` part. Thank you for your time.

Comment: My mistake, you need to concatenate the query string separately to the `sp_executesql` call. I've updated the answer accordingly.